# "cannot find symbol: method" but the method is declared

Tags: java

In my driver program, this line gives me `cannot find symbol` error and I don't know why. The method is clearly defined in the `SavingsAccount` class, and I can refer to all other methods in my driver program but just not that one, I tried changing the type to `double`, and etc but still not working.

```
Account acct2 = new SavingsAccount (name);
acct2.calculateBalance();
```

`SavingsAccount` class inherits from `Account` class:

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account
{
    private final short minBalance = 0;
    private double overdraftFee;
    private double yearlyInterestRate = 0.02;
    private double interestAmount;

    public SavingsAccount (String name)
    {
        super(name);
    }

    public double withdraw (double amount)
    {
        if (accountBalance - amount >= minBalance)
        {
            accountBalance -= amount;
            System.out.print ("Withdraw Successful");
        }
        else 
        {
            accountBalance -= amount;
            overdraftFee = accountBalance * (0.10);
            accountBalance += overdraftFee;
            System.out.print ("Withdraw Succesful, however overdraft fee of 10% has been applied to your account");


        }

        return accountBalance;
    }

// ----------------- this is the method I try to invoke -----------------------------
    public void calculateBalance ()
    {
        interestAmount = (accountBalance * yearlyInterestRate);
        accountBalance += interestAmount;
    }
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + " Interest Received: " + interestAmount;
    }


}
```

Account class, if needed

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public abstract class Account
{
    protected double accountBalance;
    protected long accountNumber;
    protected String accountHolder;
    public Account (String name)
    {
        accountHolder = name;
        accountBalance = 0;
        Random accountNo = new Random();
        accountNumber  = accountNo.nextInt(100000);
    }

    public double deposit (double amount)
    {
        accountBalance += amount;

        return accountBalance;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        NumberFormat accountBal = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return "Account Balance: " + accountBal.format(accountBalance) + "\nAccount Number: " + accountNumber;
    }

    public String getAccountHolder()
    {
        return accountHolder;
    }

    public double getAccountBalance()
    {
        return accountBalance;
    }

    public abstract double withdraw (double amount);

}
```

Comment: The method calculateBalance () is solely belongs to class SavingsAccount i.e you are not over riding it. To use your code working parent class Account should declare it or implement it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Account acct2 = new SavingsAccount (name);
acct2.calculateBalance();
```

This is because although you have an object of `SavingsAccount` you are using refrence variable of type `Account` so you can access only those methods that are there in `Account` class.

And you don't have `calculateBalance()` method in your `Account` class.

That's why you are not able to access it and compiler complains that it cannot find a method named `calculateBalance`  as it sees that reference type is `Account` and there is no such method inside `Account` class.

If you want to use that method then change reference type to `SavingsAccount` :

```
SavingsAccount acct2 = new SavingsAccount (name);
```

Or you can explicitly cast it when accessing that method

```
((SavingsAccount) acct2).calculateBalance();
```

but be alert that it can throw `ClassCastException` if `acct2` object is actually not an object of `SavingsAccount`

**UPDATE:**

*But
remember that at runtime, Java uses virtual method invocation to dynamically
select the actual version of the method that will run, based on the actual instance.*

Comment: I thought polymorphism reference gave me the ability to do thos

Comment: because you have defined `withdraw` method in `Account` class though it is abstract

Comment: Guess i didnt have the concept fully checked

Comment: @Aaron see my update and you should clear your concepts about polymorphism

Answer (score 1):

Try switching,

```
Account acct2 = new SavingsAccount (name);
acct2.calculateBalance();
```

To

```
SavingsAccount acct2 = new SavingsAccount (name);
acct2.calculateBalance();
```

Or (Not sure why you would want to), I believe you could cast `acct2` to `SavingsAccount`.

Answer (score 0):

"All other methods" are coming from `Account`, not `SavingsAccount`. When you are wanting to call `cCalculateBalance`, try it like this:

```
(SavingsAccount)acct2.calculateBalance()
```