# How to create an arraylist using polymorphism?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create an array list that contains all employees and is able to handle any type of employee. I also have to load the data onto to the list The class I'm using is called payroll. This is what I have so far:

The employee class looks like this:

```
 import java.util.*;
 public abstract class Employee
{
private String name, employeeNum, department;
private char type;

public Employee()
{
    name ="";
    employeeNum = "";
    department = "";
 }

public Employee(String Name, String EmpNum, String Depart)
{
   name = Name;
   employeeNum = EmpNum;
   department = Depart;
}

//public EMpoy

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getEmployeeNum()
{
    return employeeNum;
}

public String getDepartment()
{
    return department;
}

public char getType()
{
    return type;
}

public void setName(String Name)
{
   name = Name; 
}

public void setEmployeeNum(String EmpNum)
{
    employeeNum = EmpNum;
}

public void setDepartment(String Depart)
{
    department = Depart;
}

public String toString()
{
    String str;

    str = "Employee Name: " + name + "\n" 
         + "Employee Number: " + employeeNum + "\n"
         + "Employee Department: " + department + "\n";

    return str;
}

}
```

The payroll class looks like this so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Payroll
{
private ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();

private String fileName;

public Payroll()
{

}

public void fileName(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("InsertFileName");
    String fileName1 = kb.next();
    fileName = fileName1 + ".txt";
}

public void loadData() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    while (s.hasNext())
      {
          String name = s.next();
          String employeeNum = s.next();
          String department = s.next();
          //String typeString = s.next();
          //char type = typeString.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
          char type = s.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

            if (type == 'S')
                {
                    double yearlySalary = s.nextDouble();

                    list.add(new Salary (name, employeeNum, department, yearlySalary));
                }
            else if (type == 'H')    
                {
                       double hourlyPayRate = s.nextDouble();
                       String hours = s.next();
                       int hoursWorked = Integer.parseInt(hours);

                       list.add(new Hourly (name, employeeNum, department, hourlyPayRate, hoursWorked));
                }
             else if (type == 'C')
                {
                    int numOfWeeks = s.nextInt();
                    double baseWeeklySalary = s.nextDouble();
                    int salesThisWeek = s.nextInt();
                    int salesThisYear = s.nextInt();
                    double commissionRate = s.nextDouble();

                    list.add(new Commission (name, employeeNum, department,     numOfWeeks, baseWeeklySalary, salesThisWeek, salesThisYear, commissionRate));
                }
        }

    s.close();  
  }
```

Now I know I'm supposed to make the arraylist in the constructor, that's what I'm having trouble with. How can I make the list using polymorphism to get every employee? Thanks.

Comment: sorry but what is `salary`, `Hourly` and `Commission` ?

Comment: Those are the types of employees.

Comment: If you're supposed to make the arraylist in the constructor, why didn't you do that? In other words, what is the issue with this code?

Comment: I don't see the problem--you appear to be using the list correctly.  Is there something that isn't working?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. There is actually an error in loading the data onto the array list. The problem is loading every last element of the arraylist. And one of the syntax errors I get is when I wrote list.get(0).getCommissionRate());, it gets a syntax error saying it "can't find symbol"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Srk93 You are getting error as your list contains the references of Employee class and Employee class does't have getCommissionRate method. You can call on Employee reference which are declared in Employee class. Create abstact method of calculateSalary() and implement in all your child classes.

Its duplicate of ["cannot find symbol: method" but the method is declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486529/cannot-find-symbol-method-but-the-method-is-declared)