# Java - How to create edges on Arangodb?

Tags: java, arangodb

I created an edge collection using java, but when i try to create a document i get an error on method (insertEdge).

Does anyone know of another method for doing this, or what I might be doing wrong?

```
BaseEdgeDocument myObject = new BaseEdgeDocument("TurmaA/asd","TurmaA/testepedro");
myObject.addAttribute(nome.getField(), nome.getValue());
collection.insertEdge(myObject, new EdgeCreateOptions());
```

PS- the error given is a "cannot find symbol (method)"

[image: Image of the problem]

Comment: Adding the error log to the question would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading about [cannot find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486529/cannot-find-symbol-method-but-the-method-is-declared) your object (`collection`)  which you're trying to invoke the `insertEdge` method on probably isn't of type `edge collection` - hence it doesn't have `insertEdge-method`.

The [example code shows how to work with edge collections](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/blob/master/src/test/java/com/arangodb/example/graph/BaseGraphTest.java):

```java
private static EdgeEntity saveEdge(final CircleEdge edge) throws ArangoDBException {
        return db.graph(GRAPH_NAME).edgeCollection(EDGE_COLLECTION_NAME).insertEdge(edge);
}
```